# Python Regex to add a "?" to the beginning of a word in a word list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
#open text file
with open('words') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
    #pull out all 3 letter words using regular expression and add to wordlist
    word_list += re.findall(r'\b(\w{3})\b', line)
```

I use this to find all 3 letter words in a dictionary. From there, I want to add a question mark to the beginning of each word. I assume I need the `re.sub` function, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b\w{3}\b', r'?\g<0>', line)`

Comment: How about `word_list = ['?' + word for word in word_list]` outside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`, where `\1` refers to the first capture group:

```
re.sub(r'\b(\w{3})\b', r'?\1', line)
```

Comment: Err `\1` is the first capture group

Comment: Should it look like this?

`with open('words') as f:
     for line in f.readlines():

  word_list += re.findall(r'\b(\w{3})\b', line)
  re.sub(r'\b(\w{3})\b', r'?\1', line)
  print(word_list)`

Comment: @William Do you *have* to use `re.sub` here? It does make more sense to use `re.findall` to get the words you want, then use string formatting to adjust those words.

Comment: No I don't have to, I'm just trying to crack a password so no restrictions on syntax.  I see you message below, but get a syntax error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways, one of them is to get all your 3 letters words and then update them afterwards, otherwise, you can do along the lines of what you're doing and extend a list as you go. There's not really a need for `re.sub` here if you want to end up building a list of 3 letters words prefixed with `?`

Sample `words` file:

```
the quick brown fox called bob jumped over the lazy dog
and went straight to bed
cos bob needed to sleep right now
```

Sample code:

```
word_list = []
with open('words') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        matches = re.findall(r'\b(\w{3})\b', line)
        word_list.extend(f'?{word}' for word in matches)
```

Sample `word_list` after run:

```
['?the',
 '?fox',
 '?bob',
 '?the',
 '?dog',
 '?and',
 '?bed',
 '?cos',
 '?bob',
 '?now']
```

Comment: It throws invalid syntax -

`File "/root/Downloads/jane.py", line 40
    word_list.extend(f'?{word}' for word in matches)
                              ^
`
The syntax error is after {word}'

Comment: @William so change `word_list.extend(f'?{word}' for word in matches)` to `word_list.extend('?' + word for word in matches)` ?

Answer (score 0):

First compile pattern:

```
re.compile(r'\b(\w{3})\b')
```

and then use it like this:

```
word_list += '?' + re.search(line)
```

Comment: search() looks like it takes 2 arguments, not just one.  That's the error I get at least.